# Sort values for each key in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries `df` and `hf`. The key in both dictionaries is the same `id` field.
I have written code that writes values from hf and value from df into a file matched by the 'id'.

However, before I write to the file, I need the df dictionary sorted by the key and (!!!) the lists within the value ordered ascendingly by the first number of each list.

Here is data in `df`:

```
{78: [(20.0, 1.0),
  (164.0, 1.0),
  (12.0, 1.0),
  (419.0, 1.0)],
 11: [(175.0, 1.0),
  (17.0, 1.0),
  (879.0, 1.0),
  (1466.0, 1.0)],
 190: [(175.0, 1.0),
  (2.0, 1.0),
  (12.0, 1.0),
  (9.0, 1.0)]}
```

Here's the data in `hf`

```
{33: 1,
 64: 1,
1141: 1,
 1152: 1,
 190: 1,
3287: 1,
 3290: 1,
 3331: 1}
```

Sorted df should look like this:

```
{11: [(17.0, 1.0),
  (175.0, 1.0),
  (879.0, 1.0),
  (1466.0, 1.0)],
78: [(12.0, 1.0),
  (20.0, 1.0),
  (164.0, 1.0),
  (419.0, 1.0)],
190: [(2.0, 1.0),
  (9.0, 1.0),
  (12.0, 1.0),
  (175.0, 1.0)]}
```

Here is my code:

```
for key in df:
    if key in hf: 
       deliverable.write(bytes(f"{1} {bag_to_svmlight(df[key])}\n", 'utf-8'))
    else: 
       deliverable.write(bytes(f"{0} {bag_to_svmlight(df[key])}\n", 'utf-8'))
```

I was hoping the sorting could happen between for condition and if. I was thinking I could just sort items in the value of df[key] before inserting it to the write statement.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you are looking to sort a dictionary by keys use `dict(sorted(df.items()))`

Comment: What help do you need exactly? Please [edit] to clarify. Show us what you've already tried and what research you've done, and how it hasn't worked.

Comment: BTW, you have two variables named "key", that's confusing. And what's `bag_to_svmlight`? If it's not relevant to the problem, then for the sake of example, just remove it. For reference see [mre].

Comment: @wjandrea There's only one variable named `key`. The second line is `if`, not `for`.

Comment: @Barmar Oops, my bad! OP said "writes values from hf and value from df into a file" so I was cued up to expect data coming from `hf`. Now that I look again, it seems like `hf` also isn't relevant to the problem so should be removed for an MRE.

Answer (score 0):

Do the sorting in the `for` construction:

```
for key in sorted(df):
```

This will output to the file in the sorted order of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, you can sort the values within the df dictionary before writing to the file. You can use the sorted function with a custom key to achieve the desired sorting.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
def bag_to_svmlight(bag):
    # Your bag_to_svmlight implementation goes here
    pass

df = {
    78: [(20.0, 1.0), (164.0, 1.0), (12.0, 1.0), (419.0, 1.0)],
    11: [(175.0, 1.0), (17.0, 1.0), (879.0, 1.0), (1466.0, 1.0)],
    190: [(175.0, 1.0), (2.0, 1.0), (12.0, 1.0), (9.0, 1.0)]
}

hf = {33: 1, 64: 1, 1141: 1, 1152: 1, 190: 1, 3287: 1, 3290: 1, 3331: 1}

# Sort df by key
sorted_df = dict(sorted(df.items()))

with open('your_file.txt', 'wb') as deliverable:
    for key in sorted_df:
        if key in hf:
            # Sort the list within df[key] by the first element of each tuple
            sorted_values = sorted(sorted_df[key], key=lambda x: x[0])
            deliverable.write(bytes(f"{1} {bag_to_svmlight(sorted_values)}\n", 'utf-8'))
        else:
            # Sort the list within df[key] by the first element of each tuple
            sorted_values = sorted(sorted_df[key], key=lambda x: x[0])
            deliverable.write(bytes(f"{0} {bag_to_svmlight(sorted_values)}\n", 'utf-8'))
```

In this version, sorted_df is created by sorting the items of df by key. Then, within the loop, the values corresponding to each key are sorted before writing to the file. The sorting is done using the sorted function with a lambda function as the key argument, which sorts the tuples based on their first element.

Comment: There's no need for a new dictionary if you just want to control the order of the `for` loop.